# Pyspark: forward fill only on a certain hour and minute for every date

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How do I do a forward fill only where the date timestamp is 00:00:00?

For every `date` that has a `00:00:00` there will be a Null, because a sensor does not work properly. Other times there will be nulls, be they need to be kept.

```
+---+-------------------+-----+
| id|               date|value|
+---+-------------------+-----+
| A1|2016-09-30 23:00:00|    3|
| A1|2016-10-01 00:00:00| Null|
| A1|2016-10-01 01:00:00|    1|
| A1|2016-10-01 02:30:30|    3|
| A9|2016-10-05 23:00:00|    3|
| A9|2016-10-06 00:00:00| Null|
| A9|2016-10-06 02:20:00|    4|
| A9|2016-10-06 03:20:00| Null|
+---+-------------------+-----+
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
+---+-------------------+-----+
| id|               date|value|
+---+-------------------+-----+
| A1|2016-09-30 23:00:00|    3|
| A1|2016-10-01 00:00:00|    3|
| A1|2016-10-01 01:00:00|    1|
| A1|2016-10-01 02:30:30|    3|
| A9|2016-10-05 23:00:00|    3|
| A9|2016-10-06 00:00:00|    3|
| A9|2016-10-06 02:20:00|    4|
| A9|2016-10-06 03:20:00| Null|
+---+-------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")

df.withColumn("value", F.when(col("date").like("%00:00:00"), \
        F.lag("value").over(w)).otherwise(col("value"))).show()

+---+-------------------+-----+
| id|               date|value|
+---+-------------------+-----+
| A1|2016-09-30 23:00:00|    3|
| A1|2016-10-01 00:00:00|    3|
| A1|2016-10-01 01:00:00|    1|
| A1|2016-10-01 02:30:30|    3|
| A9|2016-10-05 23:00:00|    3|
| A9|2016-10-06 00:00:00|    3|
| A9|2016-10-06 02:20:00|    4|
| A9|2016-10-06 03:20:00| null|
+---+-------------------+-----+
```